# Probability that the sum of $k$ matrices is invertible

Tags: probability, matrices, inverse

Suppose we have $k$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_q$ of size $n \times n$, where $q \gg k$ and the entries of the matrices are chosen uniformly at random. Assume $q$ to be prime and we do not pick any matrix with all $0$ entries.

Can we obtain a bound on the probability that the sum of $k$ matrices is invertible?